# How to get result of Observer in subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have two `Observable` requests to server:

```
this.initService.__init__(res).subscribe((profile) => {
    console.log(profile); // It works
    this.initService.initializePeriod(profile).subscribe((period) => {
        console.log(period); // It does not work
    });

});
```

When first gets response it calls second, but I can not get result for second subscribe. I know, better to use Promises in this case, but I need pass result from first request to second, promises dont allow to do this.

I tried to use this, but Alert message does not work:

```
 this.initService.__init__(res)
            .pipe(
              mergeMap(profile => this.initService.initializePeriod(profile)))
              .subscribe((response) => {
              alert('aa');

});
```

Also tried this:

```
this.initService.__init__(res)
              .mergeMap(profile => this.initService.initializePeriod(profile))
              .subscribe((response) => {
              alert('aa');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` rxjs operators to chain the observables.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.initService.__init__(res)
.pipe(
   switchMap(profile=> this.initService.initializePeriod(profile))
).subscribe((period) => {
    console.log(period);
});
```

If you want to have response from both then use `mergeMap`

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.initService.__init__(res)
.pipe(
   mergeMap(
      profile=> this.initService.initializePeriod(profile), 
     (profile, period) => {
       return [profile,period];
}
   )
).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response[0]); //profile
    console.log(response[1]); //period
});
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wy26a7

Comment: Okay, how to transmit `profile` variable inside last subscribe?

Comment: I see two requests are working, but I still can not get common result, I do alert() in response, but dont get it

Comment: It is very weird line: ``` profile => this.initService.initializePeriod(profile), (profile, period) => {
                  return [profile, period];
                } ```

Comment: I tried this. but alert does not work: `  this.initService.__init__(res)
            .pipe(
              mergeMap(profile => this.initService.initializePeriod(profile)))
              .subscribe((response) => {
              alert('aa'); `

Comment: Did you look at the demo ? both results are coming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the result that you are getting from your first API call (profile). Check your browser console. Chances are that the profile is probably a JSON, not a valid URL. The request will not go through if the URL is not valid.

If you provide a valid URL, API call inside another API call should work.

Comment: I checked this, both return response from server

Comment: I am assuming that the function calls : `initService.__init__ () and initService.initializePeriod()` is only for minimal reproduction and you are  actually making the http calls at that place. Is this correct ?

Comment: I guess problem is in HTTP interceptor, I will check